# Scala advantages of Seq.newBuilder over Seq vars

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Currently in my application, I'm using `var fooSeq: Seq[Foo] = Seq.empty` and then using `:+` to append items. I understand that this could lead to multithreading issues and potential race conditions, but so far have not had any issues.

I recently discovered `Seq.newBuilder()` and seems this might be the preferred way to use Scala sequences. I'm wondering if the performance benefit is advantageous over using vars, and any other types of benefits that it may bring

Comment: All builders will be the fastest way to imperatively and incrementally build a collection. But, unless contained in the scope of a single method, their mutability may be dangerous. Also, another problem is that a **builder** is not a **collection**, so you have to call `result()` _(I believe that is how it is called)_ at the end, so you can not use the intermediate steps; which you can with an immutable collection in a `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you are concerned with thread-safety then a common approach is to use Java's `AtomicReference` to wrap your mutable variable like so:

`val fooSeq: AtomicReference[Seq[Foo]] = new AtomicReference(Seq.empty)`

and that would be the better approach if you need intermediate results rather than going with the Builder.

If you don't need intermediate results then Builders are generally better. (Though as Luis Miguel mentions in a comment Builders are internally mutable and not necessarily thread-safe)

A third alternative is to use a mutable data structure from Scala's `collections`: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

You might be interested in: `MutableList`, however this would still need the `AtomicReference` wrapping for thread-safety if that is a concern. There are some data structures that are natively thread-safe like `TrieMap` and those are available in `collections.concurrent`

Comment: _"An odd thing about Scala is that they can be declared as val"_, what is odd of that? - _"and those are available in collections.concurrent"_, AFAIK `collections.concurrent` shouldn't be used, and rather fallback to the **Java** ones.

Comment: In haskell you would need to wrap mutable values in a State-like Monad for mutability to happen. "val" is very misleading about immutability.

Comment: `val` means the reference is immutable, meaning the value of the variable can not be changed. If the value is internally mutable is outside of the scope of that.

Comment: Sure, that is a more accurate portrayal of "val/var" in Scala, however "val" is normally just portrayed as "immutable" without that caveat.

Comment: Thank you to both of you guys for the comments, learned a bit from both of you guys. I decided Seq.newBuilder() is not in my favor since I do need to perform intermediate steps on my seq, and Fabian I will look into some of the resources you provided. Thanks!